# WEBrick server keeps shutting down

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, webrick

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and setting up a project for the first time. Every time I try to start the WEBrick server it boots up and then shuts down. Any help would be appreciated. It seems like I need to provide the password, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
bkuethen$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/bkuethen/Dropbox/Rails Sites/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bkuethen/Dropbox/Rails Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/bkuethen/Dropbox/Rails Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bkuethen/Dropbox/Rails Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/bkuethen/Dropbox/Rails Sites/simple_cms/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/bkuethen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Gems

```
actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.2)
i18n (0.6.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.0)
json (1.8.0, 1.7.7)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.4)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0, 3.12.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.1)
```

UPDATE with database file config:

```
    # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key information from the first line of your stack trace:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

You have a password set for your root user.  You simply need to add that root password to your database.yml here:

```
development:
  ...
  password: MYPASSWORDHERE
  ...
```

Save the file, and restart Webrick.

If you don't remember the root password for MySQL, you'll need to reset it, as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The server has problems with accessing the database. Did you check your database.yml to see if the configs are right?

Comment: Try accessing the database in terminal

Comment: I updated the code above to show the database file. I'm not sure what it should look like. It's looking for the root. I can access  mysql through Terminal.

Comment: were you able to connect to mysql using "mysql -u root" without password from the terminal?